# Git's subtree merge strategy doesn't pick the right directory

Tags: git, git-submodules, subtree, git-subtree

I have a repository that looks something like this:

```
foo/
    subrepo/
        a_file_in_subrepo
        another.ext
    unrelated_file
```

`subrepo` is a repository on github, and I have a remote in my repository, say `sub`, that tracks it, but none of the files are merged.

What I want is to merge in `sub/master` at the `subrepo` folder. I know that `a_file_in_subrepo` and `another.ext` are exactly as they are in `sub/master` but if I run `git merge -s subtree sub/master` I don't get what I want, and instead get:

```
foo/
    subrepo/
        a_file_in_subrepo
        another.ext
    unrelated_file
    a_file_in_subrepo
    another.ext
```

I'm really confused. I know it guesses the directory to merge into automagically, can I override that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git confused when merging an update into my subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306595/git-confused-when-merging-an-update-into-my-subtree)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-Xsubtree=<path>` option to the `recursive` merge strategy:

```
git merge -s recursive -Xsubtree=subrepo sub/master
```